# XMLSpy for web services apps?

Tags: xml, web-services, xsd, xmlspy

[wikipedia says](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMLSpy) says

> XMLSpy is an XML editor and integrated development environment (IDE)
>   developed by Altova. XMLSpy allows developers to create  XML-based and
>   Web services applications using technologies such as XML, XBRL, XML
>   Schema, XSLT, XPath, XQuery, WSDL and SOAP.

As per my understanding XMLSpy is used to convert XSD to XML or vice versa or XML editing. But I am not sure how XML spy helps
in creating web services apps ?

Comment: I'd say because WSDL is an XML Schema Definition.

Comment: so you mean XML spy can create XML out of WSDL. Is it ?